# Cannot insert NULL value into column 'CoffeeShopId' despite field being nullable in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, migration

I'm experiencing an issue with my ASP.NET Core application where I have a one-to-many relationship between the User and CoffeeShop entities.

```
// One-to-Many: CoffeeShop to Users (Employees and Managers)
            builder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOne(u => u.CoffeeShop)
                .WithMany(cs => cs.Employees).IsRequired(false)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.CoffeeShopId)
                .IsRequired(false);
```

I want to make the CoffeeShopId field in the User entity nullable because I don't require every user to be assigned to a coffee shop.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    // ...

    public CoffeeShop? CoffeeShop { get; set; }
    public Guid? CoffeeShopId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Despite making the CoffeeShopId property nullable, I encounter the following exception when trying to register a new user:

```
SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CoffeeShopId', table 'LuxusCoffee2.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

However, when I inspect the SQL script that was executed to create the AspNetUsers table, the CoffeeShopId column is defined as nullable:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    -- ...
    [CoffeeShopId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, -- Allow NULL values
    -- ...
);
```

I'm unable to identify the cause of this issue. Could someone please help me understand why I'm still getting this error despite setting the CoffeeShopId field as nullable in my code and seeing the corresponding column as nullable in the database schema?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote on the question? - Since you are using SQL Server, use the SQL Server Management Studio. Right-click the table | Script Table as | CREATE To | New Query Editor Window. Check if the column is really defined nullable. If nullable, insert a NULL value using an INSERT INTO script or Right-click | Edit on the table. Like this you know if the problem is in SQL Server or elsewhere.

Comment: Has it always been Nullable<Guid> in your data model? Seems like your migration script isn't getting applied and the actual column in the database is defined `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL`. Could it be that the migration script is targeting a different server/instance/database than the one your application is using?

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeShopId in your users table is a foreign key. In the model you should [give it the type](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16490#issuecomment-508971362) `Nullable<Guid>`